# Valgrind, Helgrind uses >90% of CPU and doesn't produce results

Tags: linux, valgrind

I'm running Valgrind's Helgrind tool on a program in a script.

Here's the relevant part of the script:
(The only line I wrote is the first one)

```
    sudo valgrind --tool=helgrind ./core-linux.bin --reset PO 2>> ../Test_CFE_SB/valgrindLog.txt &
    PID=$!
    printf "\n" >> ../Test_CFE_SB/valgrindLog.txt
    sleep $sleepTime
    #did it crash?
    ps ax | grep $PID | grep -vc grep
    RESULT=$?
    if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]
    then
        sudo kill $PID
        echo "Process killed by buildscript."
    else
        echo $name >> crash.log
```

OS: 32 bit XUbuntu 14.04

The program helgrind is running on, core-linux.bin, does not shut down by it self, like a server. Runs until it gets a kill command.

What happens is that the program shuts down after the kill $PID command but Helgrind keeps going in the background taking about 94% of the CPU according to top. I then have to kill it using kill -9 and valgrindLog.txt only contains the starting message from Valgrind, no report or anything. I have let it run through the night with the same result so it's not that it's just slow.

I ran the exact same script except used --tool=memcheck instead and that runs perfectly well. valgrindLog.txt contains everything it should and all is well there. Same if I use --tool=drd, all good. But helgrind doesn't want to play ball and unfortunately I'm not so familiar with Valgrind that I can figure this out on my own, so far at least.

Answer (score 0):

To see what your application is doing under Valgrind/helgrind,
you can attach using gdb+vgdb and examine if your program advances
or else, where it stays blocked.

If you cannot attach, then it means that Valgrind is running in its own
code, and that might be a valgrind/helgrind bug.

If you have a small reproducer, file a bug in valgrind bugzilla